# NotesRichTextItem.getMIMEEntity() always returns null

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, richtext

I have a notes form with a rich text field on it, called "Body". I've set the "Storage" property of the field to "Store contents as HTML and MIME".

Now, I am creating a new document with that form in the Notes Client.

However, if I try to access the rich text field's value in SSJS with NotesRichTextItem.getMIMEEntity(), it always returns null.

Am I missing something?

Thank you for your help in advance.

**Update 2: 02/12/2015**

I did some more testing and I found the cause, why it won't recognize the rich text field as MIME Type, but rather always returns it as RICH TEXT:

The cause is me accessing the database with "sessionAsSigner" rather than just using "database".

If I remove "sessionAsSigner" and use "database" instead, making the XPage unavailable to public access users, so, I am forced to log in, the code recognizes it as MIME Type and I can get a handle on NotesMIMEEntity.

Unfortunately, the XPage has to be available to public access users and I have to use sessionAsSigner.

When I open the document properties and I look at the rich text field, I can see that the "Field Flags" are "SIGN SEAL". My guess is, that's why sessionAsSigner doesn't work, but it is just a guess.

Any ideas?

**Update 1: 02/12/2015**

Here is the code I am using in my SSJS:

```
var oDBCurrent:NotesDatabase = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(session.getServerName(), session.getCurrentDatabase().getFilePath());
var oVWMailProfiles:NotesView = oDBCurrent.getView('$vwSYSLookupEmailProfiles');
var oVWPWResetRecipient:NotesView = oDBCurrent.getView('$vwPWPMLookupPWResetNotificationProfiles');
var oDocPWResetRecipient:NotesDocument = null;
var oDocMailProfile:NotesDocument = null;
var oDocMail:NotesDocument = null;

var sServer = session.getServerName();

oDocPWResetRecipient = oVWPWResetRecipient.getDocumentByKey(sServer, true);
oDocMailProfile = oVWMailProfiles.getDocumentByKey('.MailTemplate', true);
oDocMail = oDBCurrent.createDocument();

//Set default fields
oDocMail.replaceItemValue('Form', 'Memo');
oDocMail.replaceItemValue('Subject', oDocMailProfile.getItemValueString('iTxtSubject'));
oDocMail.replaceItemValue('SendTo', oDocPWResetRecipient.getItemValue('iNmesRecipients'))

//Get body text
var oItem:NotesItem = oDocMailProfile.getFirstItem("Body");
var entity:NotesMIMEEntity = oItem.getMIMEEntity();

//Create email body
var tmp = entity.getContentAsText();

//Replace <part2> with part 2 of the password
tmp = @ReplaceSubstring(tmp, "&lt;part2&gt;", sPWPart2);

//Set content of Body field as MIME type                                            
var body = oDocMail.createMIMEEntity();
var stream = session.createStream();                                
stream.writeText(tmp);
body.setContentFromText(stream, "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1", 0);        

//Send email
oDocMail.send();
```

As I mentioned before, I've also tried:

```
var oDBCurrent:NotesDatabase = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(session.getServerName(), session.getCurrentDatabase().getFilePath());
var oVWMailProfiles:NotesView = oDBCurrent.getView('$vwSYSLookupEmailProfiles');
var oVWPWResetRecipient:NotesView = oDBCurrent.getView('$vwPWPMLookupPWResetNotificationProfiles');
var oDocPWResetRecipient:NotesDocument = null;
var oDocMailProfile:NotesDocument = null;
var oDocMail:NotesDocument = null;

var sServer = session.getServerName();

oDocPWResetRecipient = oVWPWResetRecipient.getDocumentByKey(sServer, true);
oDocMailProfile = oVWMailProfiles.getDocumentByKey('.MailTemplate', true);
oDocMail = oDBCurrent.createDocument();


//Set default fields
oDocMail.replaceItemValue('Form', 'Memo');
oDocMail.replaceItemValue('Subject', oDocMailProfile.getItemValueString('iTxtSubject'));
oDocMail.replaceItemValue('SendTo', oDocPWResetRecipient.getItemValue('iNmesRecipients'))

//Get body text
var entity:NotesMIMEEntity = oDocMailProfile.getMIMEEntity('Body');

//Create email body
var tmp = entity.getContentAsText();

//Replace <part2> with part 2 of the password
tmp = @ReplaceSubstring(tmp, "&lt;part2&gt;", sPWPart2);

//Set content of Body field as MIME type                                            
var body = oDocMail.createMIMEEntity();
var stream = session.createStream();                                
stream.writeText(tmp);
body.setContentFromText(stream, "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1", 0);        

//Send email
oDocMail.send();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling sessionAsSigner.setConvertMime(false)

Answer (score 0):

You get the MIMEEntity from the document, not from the Richtext item. See an example here (starting at line 103): https://github.com/zeromancer1972/OSnippets/blob/master/CustomControls/ccSnippets.xsp

Comment: Hello Oliver, thank you for your response. I've tried that too by calling "var entity:NotesMIMEEntity = NotesDocument.getMIMEEntity("Body");", where "Body" is the name of the rich text field. But it returns null as well. Any other ideas?

Comment: So it obviously depends on where the content was created. Did you tested to create/save the content via the XPage instead of using a Notes form? Does this make any difference? Sorry, I have no working example right now so I am actually guessing and brainstorming right now... My example from above works when the content is created via an XPage.

Comment: That might actually be it. I'll give that a try. When I create the document in the Notes Client with the Form and I show the document properties, I can see that the Data Type of the field Body is "MIME Part", so, it should be fine, but obviously is not. However, I had the code write out the type of the field and it comes back as 1, which is RICHTEXT, very weird. I'll give creating the document with an XPage a try and let you know. Thank you again for your help, I appreciate it

Comment: I've tried creating the document with an XPage, but no luck. The type of the field still comes back as 1 (RICHTEXT) even though in the document properties, it is listed as type "MIME Part".

Comment: This is very strange: just tested your scenario with my app, created new content via Notes form (RTF set to MIME) and my code from above displays the MIME part without any problem. Maybe you can post your whole code block where you read the content?

Comment: The main difference between our two approaches is that you fetch the document via SSJS and I do it via a data source I get from my repeat control. Maybe you try to get your "profile" from a datasource you attach to the XPage or a panel and refer to it in your SSJS then. That's my last idea so far :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should set the session to not convert MIME to RichText.
Add this at the start of your code.

```
session.setConvertMime(false);
```

Comment: Hello Ferry, thank you very much for your response. I've tried that and it doesn't work either. However, I found the cause, why it is not working and I'll post it as Update 2 in my original question.